# Aravis: Buffer underrun causes timeout

Tags: computer-vision, genicam, aravis, gigevision

I'm using the **Aravis library** with a GenICam ethernet camera.

If I don’t call `arv_stream_timeout_pop_buffer()` often enough and Aravis runs out of input buffers and gets buffer underruns, after a while (a few calls) I start to get `ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT` status on my buffers. Why does buffer underrun cause timeouts to happen? What can I do about it?

Comment: you created the aravis tag. that suggests a poor chance that anyone on this site will know how to help you. -- when in doubt, file a bug report: https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis